# save date without time and timezone in Google App Engine

Tags: date, google-app-engine

When I save a date in GAE datastore, it saves with time and timezone. I only want to save the date like ***yyyy/MM/dd*** without timezone, a**nd I want to take Date as datatype not String.**

How to do it?

Comment: what do you mean w/o timezone? UTC? I believe it's already in UTC

Comment: I mean, it is saving in "2016-04-22 (16:00:00.000) AKDT" format. but i want to save it as 2016-04-22 only (no time & timezone)

Comment: Why not set the time to midnight? Essentially a date object is a `Long` Unix microtime. So all you'd do would be to substract `mod 1000*60*60*24` which would be midnight of that day.

Comment: What leads you to think it's storing a timezone? If you're using Python you can use an `ndb.DateProperty`.  Note from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#Date_and_Time): **no explicit time zone information is stored in the Datastore**. But I also like @konqi's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little weird, but when you save a date to a DateProperty in the data store, Google actually stores it as a datetime.  See [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#DateProperty).

I believe when you retrieve it, you will get a time with your date, but since the time is just zeros, it is easy to convert it to a date and discard the time.

If this is a problem, then you can use a PickleProperty to store the actual Python date object (assuming you are using Python) in the datastore.

Comment: I am using java actually, and I am retrieving record from GAE using filter of startDate Equal to <sth>. and this sth is only Date without timezone. But Here timezone in DB differs so query gives null. even though date is same.

Comment: The problem is that the timezone also saves the offset in hours based on the timezone set on the server